# How can future magento crons show as 'Too late for the schedule'

Tags: magento-1.7

[image: Magento Crons]

In the picture, the red vertical line represents now. Red bars in the future are showing the message 'Too late for the schedule'. How is this even possible? My web servers and database all have synchronized time (UTC). I'm using Mirasvit Asynchronous index and also AOE Scheduler.

[image: Config]

Cron is configured according to system config below. System cron runs every five minutes.

Do the crons fire from top to bottom? Could a fatal error in one of the upper methods be causing aysncindex never to be reached? It still doesn't answer why scheduler shows future tasks as "Too late."

Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, and it may not matter at all, but what timezone is your store set to?

Comment: In Magento admin timezone is set to Australia/Sydney. This should interpret system time correctly to our timezone. And it does seem to do that. Times shown are Sydney time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AOE Scheduler I was seeing weird bars where it looked like a certain cron was running for a really long time but according to logs they were only running for a second or so. I checked in that cron and it had the code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
```

The cron itself was overriding the Magento timezone which was causing following cron tasks to think they'd missed their chance to run. This was a tricky one to diagnose but glad it got sorted.